# How to convert JSON data array object to custom string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

CURRENT RESULT:

```
master data :`[object Object]`

with stringify: 

    [{"bundlingId":"10547","countqtybuy":1}, 
     {"bundlingId":"19386","countqtybuy":2}]

with toString: `[object Object]`

with toString + stringify: 

    [{"bundlingId":"10547","countqtybuy":1},
     {"bundlingId":"19386","countqtybuy":2}]
```

MY EXPECTED RESULT :

```
10547,1;19386,2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Your expected result when doing what? You need to loop in some way - map would be useful

Comment: Hi, you need to traverse the 'master data' array, f.i. using `forEach` to build the string with your needed format. Check this: https://jsbin.com/canuxedunu/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see you are on the wrong track I post this for you

```js
const obj = JSON.parse`[{"bundlingId":"10547","countqtybuy":1},
 {"bundlingId":"19386","countqtybuy":2}]`
  
 const values = obj.map(item => Object.values(item).join(",")).join(";")
 console.log(values)
```